# Notifications to community users on password change

Tags: workflow, process-builder, customer-community

I have portal (community) users, which are created from Contact > Manage External User. This user also can be viewed/changed from Contact > Manage External User > View Customer User. If I change the email for this user - he never gets any notification that the email is changed. Is there any way I can send notifications for such user? I tried to create WF rule, and process (via process builder), but cannot configure to send email to contact if User email is changed.
Any advice?